# How to create text file in a directory and add text to it in one command from terminal

Tags: linux, terminal

I'm doing an assignment on terminal commands in Ubuntu. The problem I'm currently stuck on asks me to create a text file in a directory I'm not currently in, and add text to it, all using one command. I was trying to run it as:

```
touch /home/user/Desktop/index.html
echo "text" > index.html
...
```

but keep getting errors.

Comment: `echo test > /path/to/file`

Comment: "but keep getting errors". You command is close, but not exactly right, but there is nothing there that should generate an error message, unless the path `/home/user/Desktop` doesn't exist. Please edit your Q to include the exact text of the error message. Good luck.

Comment: Please show the relevant code and state the exact problem or error. A description alone is not enough. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also see [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck).

Answer (score 2):

You also need to specify the path when writing "text" into the file:

`touch /home/user/Desktop/index.html ; echo "text" > /home/user/Desktop/index.html`

Also, there's no need to touch the file first. The `>` operator will automatically create the file if it doesn't exist, so you can just type:

`echo "text" > /home/user/Desktop/index.html`

Answer (score 1):

```
cat > /the/directory/your_file
hello world!
foo bar
baz
^D
```

comments:

- the part between cat... and ^D is text *you* enter.
- ^D (control-D) is an End-of-File marker you type to tell the program, cat, that that   is the end of the file you just created, your_file.
- If you now do `cat /the/directory/your_file`, (NOTE: no redirection operator '>' here!), you will see the contents of the file you just created.
- Be sure to type only one ^D (control-D); if you hit it twice you will find yourself logged out from the terminal...; the second ^D went to your terminal and told it 'End-of-File', which to it means, bye bye, aka. 'exit'.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use `printf`:

`printf 'Hello\nworld' > /home/user/Desktop/index.html`